# GitHub exclude README.md from download zip

Tags: github

So I'm pretty new to GitHub and I've spent the last 2 days getting to grips with it and frankly it's awesome! but you all know that already! anyhow...

I'm under the impression that you need a README.md for the page description but I have run into a problem with one of my projects and I'll do the best I can to explain the issue.

When developing Joomla plugins, modules or components your zip files need to have a folder within the zip with all your files. This causes a problem, the license and README.md file are contained outside of the parent folder, meaning when people click to download zip they get the add-on but they are unable to install it without deleting those two files beforehand.

Now correct me if I'm wrong if I use a .gitignore this will only stop tracking locally for adds, commits and pushes, not excluding those files within the download zip file.

You can view my [Joomla Webmaster Site Verification Plugin](https://github.com/SimonHayter/Webmaster-Site-Verification) on GitHub which should give you an idea what I'm talking about. Ideally, I'd like to have a page description but exclude both README.md and license when people click the download button, as they may want to install from GitHub using remote URL method.

Looking for either a workaround or a fix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

READMEs are very important to GitHub repos, and you've used yours well so I would recommend against adding those files to your `.gitignore`.

Instead, I would recommend using GitHub [releases](https://github.com/blog/1547-release-your-software) and provide the "clean" zip file there. You could also use your README to point to the latest release download link when you get that setup.

Comment: Glad it helped!